# Is there a way to have functionality of Firebug in Sublime Text 2

Tags: ftp, firebug, sublimetext2

In other words is there a way to connect Sublime Text 2 to the ftp server so that I can work on the website directly from the editor without using a separate FTP client? Also, is there a way to see the changes without updating a web page?

Comment: What do you mean by "see changes without updating a web page"? As for your first question, there are at least two relevant topics on the ST2 forum ([here](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=10415) and [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9488))

Comment: The easiest way would be to work from the FTP server's file system itself. Or do you need a way for ST2 to use the FTP protocol?

Comment: It would be really convenient to have ST2 to use the FTP protocol. The only thing I've found online is a plugin for ST2 that costs approximately the same as the program itself.